# Show that $\bigcup_{g \in C}D(g)$ in the proof of Hahn-Banach theorem is a vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis

This is from a proof of the Hahb-Banach theorem. So we have a linear functional $f $ of some subspace $Z $ of the real vector space $X $, such that $f(x) \le p(x)$, $x \in Z $, and $p $ is sublinear.

Let $E $ be the set of all linear extensions $g $ of $f $ satisfying $g(x) \le p(x) $.

On $E$ we define the partial ordering $g \le h $ meaning $D(g) \subset D(h) $ and $g(x)=h(x) $ on $D(g)  $.

For any totally ordered set $C \subset E $ define $\hat g(x)=g(x) $ if $x \in D(g) $  (and $g \in C $)

**Show that the domain of $\hat g = \bigcup_{g \in C}D(g)$ is a vector space**

*$D(g) $ denotes the domain of $g $*

---

For any two points $x _1 , x _2 \in D(\hat g) $, say $x _1 \in D(g _1) $ and $x _2 \in D(g _2) $ we must have that both points are in one domain, since $C $ is totally ordered. Say both are in $D(g _2 ) $.

How is $x _1 + x _2 $ in $D(\hat g) $? Is $D(g _2 ) $ a vector space?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the set $C$ ?

Comment: It is a totally ordered subset of $E $ ( with the same ordering as defined on $E $)

Comment: $D(g)$ is a vector space for all $g\in C$, by assumption.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Could you expand a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a rephrasing of your proof. You have a vector space $X$ and a subspace $Z$, as well as a functional $f:Z\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $f(x)\le p(x)$ for all $x\in Z$, where $p:X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is a sublinear function. The definition of $E$ is as follows: an element of $E$ is a pair $(D,g)$, consisting of a subspace $D$ containing $Z$ and an extension $g:D\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ of $f$ such that $g(x)\le p(x)$ for alle $x\in D$. The partial order on $E$ is defined as follows: $(D_1,g_1)\le (D_2,g_2)\iff D1\subset D_2$ and $g_2$ is an extension of $g_1$.

The strategy now is to use Zorn's Lemma to show that $E$ has a maximal element $(V,h)$ and then show that $V=X$. To invoke Zorn's lemma, you need to show that every totally ordered subset $C$ has an upper bound. This is done by considering $\bigcup_{(D,g)\in C}D$. Your job is to show this is a vector space and actually you already have it written down, since by assumption every $D$ is a vector space.

Comment: Thanks! what I missed is that the extensions are assumed to be linear functionals, and thus with a domain that is a vector space. I thought that we were considering just arbitrary extensions...